# parallel for is slower than sequential for

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

My program shall perform a parallel distinct rotation of words and texts.

If you do not know what this means: Rotations of "BANANA" are

- BANANA
- ANANAB
- NANABA
- ANABAN
- NABANA
- ABANAN

(simply put the first letter to the end.)

```
vector<string> rotate_sequentiell( string* word )
{
vector<string> all_rotations;

for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < word->size(); i++ )
{
    string rotated = word->substr( i ) + word->substr( 0,i );
    all_rotations.push_back( rotated );
}

if ( verbose ) { printVec(&all_rotations, "Rotations"); }


return all_rotations;
}
```

We should be able to make this parallel. Instead of moving just one letter to the end, I want to move two letters at once to the end, so for example, we take BANANA
Take te "BA" to the end and get NANA BA, which is the third entry in the list above.

I implemented it like this

```
vector<string> rotate_parallel( string* word )
{
vector<string> all_rotations( word->size() );

#pragma omp parallel for
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < word->size(); i++ )
{
    string rotated = word->substr( i ) + word->substr( 0,i );
    all_rotations[i] = rotated;
}

if ( verbose ) { printVec(&all_rotations, "Rotations"); }

return all_rotations;
}
```

I pre-calculated the number of possible rotations and used the #pragma omp parallel for, so it should do what I think it does.

To test these functions, I have a 40KB large text-file which is meant to be "rotated". I wanna have all the distinct rotations of a giant text.

What happens now is, that the sequential procedure tooks like 4.3 seconds and the parallel tooks like 6.5 seconds.

Why is that so? What am I doing wrong?

This is how I measure time:

```
clock_t start, finish;
start = clock();
bwt_encode_parallel( &glob_word, &seperator );
finish = clock();
cout << "Time (seconds): "
     << ((double)(finish - start))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

I compile my code with

g++ -O3 -g -Wall -lboost_regex -fopenmp -fmessage-length=0

Comment: `std::string` allocates memory dynamically, and these allocations need synchronisation. You're probably looking at the serial time plus the synchronisation overhead.

Comment: Don't use `clock()` to measure how much time your program is taking. Use `omp_get_wtime()`. You're currently measuring CPU time when you mean to be measuring wall time. This is absolutely your main problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parallel version has 2 sources of additional work compared to the sequential version:
(1) overhead of starting the threads, and 
(2) coordination and locking between the threads.

Impact of (1) Should diminish when the data set grows larger, and probably can't be worth 2 seconds anyway, but this would set the limit of how small jobs it makes sense to parallelize.

(2) is in your case probably mostly caused by omp assigning tasks to the threads, and the different threads doing memory allocation for the 2 intermediate substrings and the final string "rotated" - the memory allocation routine probably has to get a global lock before it can reserve a piece of the heap for you.

Preallocating the final storage in a single thread and guiding OMP to run the parallel loop in large (2048) blocks of iterations per thread tilts the result to to favor the parallel execution. I get about 700ms for the single threaded and 330ms for the multithreaded version with the code below:

```
 enum {SZ = 40960};
 std::string word;
 word.resize(SZ);
 for (int i = 0; i < SZ; i++) {
   word[i] = (i & 127) + 1;  // put stuff into the word
 }
 std::vector<std::string> all_rotations(SZ);
 clock_t start, finish;
 start = clock();
 for (int i = 0; i < (int)word.size(); i++) {
   all_rotations[i].reserve(SZ);
 }
 #pragma omp parallel for schedule (static, 2048)
 for (int i = 0; i < (int)word.size(); i++) {
   std::string rotated = word.substr(i) + word.substr(0, i);
   all_rotations[i] = rotated;
 }
 finish = clock();
 printf("Time (seconds): %0.3lf\n", ((double)(finish - start))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Last, when you need the results of the burrows wheeler transform, you don't necessarily want N copies of a string that contains N characters. It would save space and processing to treat the string as a ring buffer and read each rotation from a different offset in the buffer.

Comment: I have not read through your answer but I did scan over your code and I noticed you're using the `clock` function. I guess you're using MSVC as well because `clock` is not a good function to use except with the visual C runtime library. The use of `clock` has led to more questions on OpenMP on SO than anything else (followed by not declaring the iterator of an inner loop private). Use `omp_get_wtime()`.

Comment: Z boson: He propably used the clock function because I used it in my question in the first place. I did not know about omp_get_wtime()

Comment: You Answer helped a lot, pre-reserving the requited space in a single thread did the trick for me. I did not know about scheduling, looks like I need to dig further into this.
My program is a lot faster now.

Yes I do need the results of the Burrows Wheeler Transform. I do not know if a circular buffer would make it easier or faster to perform the rotation? I Need to think about it.